# mysqli prepared statements remove new lines

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been using "standard" mysqli queries, but decided to use prepared statements for more security. Everything works fine except that new lines are removed when data is added to the database. Here's an example of some query:

```
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($GLOBALS["mysqli"], "UPDATE products SET product_description=? WHERE product_id=?");
if ($stmt)
    {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $product_description, $product_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
```

$product_description is a variable from textarea (submitted via POST form), and it has new lines. When data is added to database, it looks like:

> FIRSTLINE\r\nSECONDLINE

I know there's nothing wrong with form or the code itself, because if I use this query:

```
mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli'], "UPDATE products SET product_description='$product_description' WHERE product_id='$product_id');
```

Everything works perfectly, data in the database looks like:

> FIRST_LINE
>
> SECOND_LINE

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your data look like when you store it in the database with `prepared` statements instead?

Comment: something else is causing that and you're not showing us, the part where you're assigning the variable to the POST array and how exactly it's entered in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. The mysqli_real_escape_string function was applied to all variables submitted via form. Removing this single function solved the problem.

In case someone experiences similar issues, just look at your code and remove mysqli_real_escape_string function - it works fine with "standard" queries, but breaks prepared statements.

Comment: where's `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in your code? `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and prepared functions are two different animals altogether.